# Serve documents from alternative document root

Tags: php, apache

I would like Apache to serve documents from

```
c:/Apache24/htdocs
```

and

```
d:/www
```

resp on my Windows local machine. In httpd-vhosts.conf I'm trying:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    DocumentRoot "c:/Apache24/htdocs"
    ServerName test.localhost
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
    <Directory "D:/www">
        AllowOverride All
        Order Deny,Allow
        Deny from all
        Allow from 127.0.0.1
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

and in hosts

```
127.0.0.1          test.localhost
```

but browsing to http://test.localhost results in a list of directories under

```
C:/htdocs
```

being displayed?

Am I getting any closer with this:

```
Alias c:/Apache24/htdocs D:/www
<Directory c:/Apache24/htdocs>
  Require all granted
</Directory>
```

If so, where do I add it? N.B. I want to store and serve web documents from D:/ since C:/ is getting rather full now.

Comment: You can serve documents just from one main folder. You could create symbolic links to other folders if you want.

Comment: you mean C:/apache24/htdocs is what you get ?

Comment: @lagbox - yes, that's what I mean.

Comment: @Hardy - could you give an example?

Comment: well you are telling it that you want that to be the document root ... so that is expected. Which domain do you want to point to which document root ? localhost goes where and test.localhost goes where ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

check you have row: `NameVirtualHost *:80` before your virtual host. That should usually be there already, but check it.

Change your host to point just into one folder like:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    DocumentRoot "D:/www"
    ServerName localserver
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
    <Directory "D:/www">
        AllowOverride All
        Order Deny,Allow
        Deny from all
        Allow from 127.0.0.1
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

Create symbolic link from your `c:/Apache24/htdocs` to for example `D:/www/apache` folder.
Then you can access to your `c:/Apache24/htdocs` folder from url:

```
localserver/apache
```

Read more about symlinks: 
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NTFS_symbolic_link

Another option is to create two urls (domains) and virtualhosts like (add this after above):

```
 <VirtualHost *:80>
        DocumentRoot "c:/Apache24/htdocs"
        ServerName other.localserver
        Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
        <Directory "c:/Apache24/htdocs">
            AllowOverride All
            Order Deny,Allow
            Deny from all
            Allow from 127.0.0.1
        </Directory>
    </VirtualHost>
```

and in your hosts:

```
127.0.0.1          localserver other.localserver
```

Comment: that's great. However sym links in Windows ain't straightforward are they? I can't just do a ln -s C:/Apache24/htdocs D:/www/apache if I recall without using third party binaries.

Comment: Sorry i don't use windows (just MAC+ubuntu) and cant answer to that. But quick googling should give you answer.

Answer (score 0):

On Windows 7 with WAMP installed on

```
C:\Apache24
```

and serving documents out of

```
C:\Apache24\htdocs
```

you may want to serve documents from the D drive instead, since C is getting full. Go to:

```
C:\Apache24\conf\extra\httpd-vhosts.conf
```

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
 DocumentRoot "D:/www/apache/site1"
 ServerName site1.dev
  <Directory "D:/www/apache/site1">
    Options Indexes MultiViews
    AllowOverride None
    Require all granted
 </Directory>
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:80>
 DocumentRoot "D:/www/apache/site2"
 ServerName site2.dev
  <Directory "D:/www/apache/site2">
    Options Indexes MultiViews
    AllowOverride None
    Require all granted
  </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

And edit:

```
C:\Windows\System32\drivers\etc\hosts
```

```
127.0.0.1           site1.dev
127.0.0.1           site2.dev
```

You should now be able to serve (locally) you're web documents from

```
D:\www\apache
```

with no need for sym links.